# How to select a specific id value not the last one mysql php

Tags: php, mysql

Hi I am trying to update a specific value from a row, but it only gets the last id no matter what and changes active to 0 just for the last row.

Any idea?
Thanks!

```
 <?php
  include 'db.php';

  $selectquery="SELECT pid from tblpes WHERE active=1";
  $result = mysqli_query($conn, $selectquery) or die("Error");
   while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
      $pid= $row['pid'];
   }


   $sqlupdate="UPDATE tblpes SET active=0 WHERE pid=$pid";

    $result1=mysqli_query($conn,$sqlupdate);


   $conn->close();
 ?>
```

Comment: in the while loop, you are always updating the variable `$pid`. There has be some sort of `if` condition there to fetch the required `$pid`.

Answer (score 2):

The last id is updated because the $pid value is replaced in the loop.

Move your update query in the loop like this :

```
include 'db.php';
$selectquery="SELECT pid from tblpes WHERE active=1";
$result = mysqli_query($conn, $selectquery) or die("Error");
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
  $pid= $row['pid'];
  $sqlupdate="UPDATE tblpes SET active=0 WHERE pid=$pid";
  $result1=mysqli_query($conn,$sqlupdate);
}
```

But if I understand what do you want to do, you can just do it :

```
 $sqlupdate="UPDATE tblpes SET active=0 WHERE active=1";
 $result1=mysqli_query($conn,$sqlupdate);
```